# Erro ao compilar projeto delphi 5. Diz que não consegue renomear arquivo

Tags: delphi

Tento rodar o aplicativo e me dá esse erro. Como eu resolvo? Delphi5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode colocar a mensagem de erro como texto?

Comment: Eu resolvi assim. Fui na pasta e renomeei o arquivo, salvei tudo no delphi e depois eu voltei ao nome original e funcionou. Essa etapa já passei. Em realidade, tudo o que eu não quero é esse projeto. Hoje desenvolvo em C# e apareceu esse projeto e me desanimou bastante.

Comment: Normal, legado é assim mesmo.